# mysql: import multiple databases from sql dump with prefix

Tags: mysql, import

I have a mysql dump in a .sql file. There are many databases in it with `DROP DATABASE` and `USE` commands before each database.

On the running server are databases with the same names. I don't want to overwrite them. How can I import all these databases with a prefix and without dropping any existing databases/tables? But existing databases with the prefix should be overwritten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's initialize some variables for ease of use:

```
DB_PREFIX=yourprefix_
FILE_MYSQLDUMP=/path/to/mysqldump.sql
```

Now get a list of existing databases (excluding tables that start with the prefix you don't mind overwriting and the information_schema and mysql tables which probably shouldn't be in mysqldump.sql anyway):

```
echo "SHOW DATABASES;" \
| mysql \
| egrep -v "^(Database|information\_schema|mysql|${DB_PREFIX}(.*))$" \
> /var/tmp/existing_databases
```

Now loop through entries in `existing_databases` and replace the CREATE DATABASE statements in `$FILE_MYSQLDUMP`:

```
while read DB_NAME;
do
  ARG_SED="-i 's/CREATE DATABASE \`"${DB_NAME}"\`/CREATE DATABASE \`"${DB_PREFIX}${DB_NAME}"\`/g'";
  eval "sed ${ARG_SED} ${FILE_MYSQLDUMP}";
done < <(cat /var/tmp/existing_databases)
```

And once more to replace the USE statements:

```
while read DB_NAME;
do
  ARG_SED="-i 's/USE \`"${DB_NAME}"\`/USE \`"${DB_PREFIX}${DB_NAME}"\`/g'";
  eval "sed ${ARG_SED} ${FILE_MYSQLDUMP}";
done < <(cat /var/tmp/existing_databases)
```

*Finally* you can import your revised database dump with `mysql < ${FILE_MYSQLDUMP}` ... and, providing there aren't any tricky instances of USE or CREATE DATABASE in your database dump's *records* (yikes) you should have overwritten databases matching `yourprefix_` and created prefixed versions of the other databases in the dump file.

Planning to do this regularly? Check out the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) - it's covers *almost* everything you need.

Credit + upvotes to [Escape a string for sed search pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-sed-search-pattern) for the `eval` method for handling `sed` arguments.